# Use Arrow for navigation in viewPager android ? i have tried different example but not succeded

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

- I want to use right and left arrow for navigation..
- i have tired by using button,but nothing happpens.
  -what i have tried is below :

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_instruction);
      preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(Instruction.this);
      viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);
      myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
      viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

    txtrank = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rank);
    tvRight=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvRight);
    tvLeft=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLeft);



   /* tvRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() < viewPager.getRight())
                  viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1,true);
          }
      });

      tvLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() > viewPager.getLeft())
                  viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()-1,true);
          }
      });*/

   // Generate sample data

  rank = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

       /* sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ShaPreferences",
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE); SharedPreferences.Editor editor =
        sharedPreferences.edit(); boolean firstTime =
        sharedPreferences.getBoolean("first", true); 

        if (firstTime) {
        editor.putBoolean("first", false); editor.commit();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Instruction.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        } else { Intent intent = new Intent(Instruction.this,
        LoginActivity.class); startActivity(intent); }*/


  }

  private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

      int NumberOfPages = 9;

      int[] res = { R.drawable.a0, R.drawable.b1, R.drawable.c2,
              R.drawable.d3, R.drawable.e4, R.drawable.f5, R.drawable.g6,
              R.drawable.h7, R.drawable.i8 };

      /*
       * int[] backgroundcolor = { 0xFF101010, 0xFF202020, 0xFF303030,
       * 0xFF404040, 0xFF505050, 0xFF101010, 0xFF202020, 0xFF303030,
       * 0xFF404040, 0xFF303030};
       */

      @Override
      public int getCount() {

          return NumberOfPages;


      }

      @Override
      public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
          return view == object;
      }

      @Override
      public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

          /*
           * TextView textView = new TextView(Instruction.this);
           * textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); textView.setTextSize(20);
           * textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
           * textView.setText(String.valueOf(position));
           */

          txtrank.setText(rank[position]);

          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(Instruction.this);
          imageView.setImageResource(res[position]);
          LayoutParams imageParams = new LayoutParams(
                  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
          imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);

          LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(Instruction.this);
          layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
          LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
          // layout.setBackgroundColor(backgroundcolor[position]);
          layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
          // layout.addView(textView);
          layout.addView(imageView);

          final int page = position;
          /*layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                   * Toast.makeText(Instruction.this, "Page " + page +
                   * " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();


              }
          });*/
          if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 7) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                      LoginActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
          }
          Log.e("at page number", String.valueOf(viewPager.getCurrentItem()));
          container.addView(layout);
          return layout;
      }

      @Override
      public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
          container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
      }

  }

   @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

          switch (v.getId())
          { 
              case R.id.left:
                   if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() < viewPager.getLeft())
                          viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()-1,true);


                  break; 

              case R.id.right:
                   if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() < viewPager.getRight())
                          viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1,true);
                  break; 

          }
  ```

  }

  ```
    private int getItem(int i) {
         return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
  }
  ```

-what i want is..user can move to next image by sliding as well as by using right or left arrow.. i am able to slide..but arrows are not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to work with sliding as well as arrows then you have to use left and right listeners like this.

```
    right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(pager.getCurrentItem() < pager.getRight())
            pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem()+1,true);
        }
    });

    left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (pager.getCurrentItem() > pager.getLeft())
                pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem()-1,true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: So it is downvoted. HUH.. You should tell me the reason

Comment: For me it is working properly .. Did you put the exact code in you switch ?

Comment: replace '<' with '>' in your left click code. thats the mistake

Comment: Ok. sure. this could be helping for someone,

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
Button leftButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.left);
    leftButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               mViewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(-1), true);
           }
        });

Button rightButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.right);
    rightButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               mViewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true);
           }
        });



private int getItem(int i) {
       return mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
}
```

Comment: That method returns current page postion +/- 1

Comment: Do you add that method in your code>>  private int getItem(int i) {
       return mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
}

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
 @Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
    int currentItemPosition = adapter.getItemPosition(viewpager.getCurrentItem());
    int itemCount = adapter.getCount();
    switch (v.getId())
    { 
        case R.id.left:
            if(currentItemPosition > 0) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentItemPosition - 1, true);
            }
            break; 

        case R.id.right:
            if(currentItemPosition < itemCount-1 ) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentItemPosition + 1, true);
            }
            break; 

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

Implement 2 buttons for left and right arrows.
in the On click function call :

a) if **left** arrow is clicked - viewPager.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_LEFT);

b) if **right** arrow is clicked - viewPager.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);